# Convert \u2764\ufe0f to UTF-8 using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, emoji, vader

I receive json data from an API:

```
json = {"lat": null, "body_text": "@edinburgh \u2764\ufe0f", "deduplicated_time": "2020-11-05T15:38:11.744710"}
```

I use Python to load the json message.

```
msg_body = json.loads(msg.body,strict=False)
```

I use VaderSentiment to extract the sentiment from the text on the body_text section of the json message.

Problem is that when red heart ❤ emoji is included as \u2764\ufe0f on the text Vader fails to predict the correct emotion. On their page they suggest that vader is translating utf-8 encoded emojis such as  and  and . I believe that \u2764\ufe0f is not UTF-8 , how can I turn it UTF-8 using python?

If the following page [emoji](http://www.iemoji.com/view/emoji/40/symbols/red-heart) is correct the \u2764\ufe0f is "python src" encoding.

Comment: Is this a string in a python script? Then its already okay. `print("\u2764\ufe0f")` should be fine. You could also  just use the emoji in the source `print("❤️")`.

Comment: That looks already decoded. Voting to close as unclear what you're asking..

Comment: Where did you see these escape sequences? Are they part of a script? Did you see them while inspecting a variable during debugging? `❤` is a UTF8 character, an emoji. This page, like almost all web pages, is UTF8-encoded, which is why that emoji is visible. `\u2764\ufe0f ` is two escape sequences that may not even exist in the string. Python 3 strings are Unicode. Perhaps your debugger displayed the emoji this way?

Comment: I think my question is clear @wim , I am getting text data through an API. The red heart emoji in this text appears as  \u2764\ufe0f so I want to  transform it to UTF-8.

Comment: The question asks what kind of encoding that is, but it’s obvious it’s not an encoding at all. If you’re getting *text* and not *bytes* then the content has already been decoded (probably by your API client). UTF-8 is another encoding, seemingly unrelated to this question.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: ❤ is not a "UTF8 character". There is no such thing. ❤ is a Unicode character, which can be encoded in UTF-8, but probably doesn't need to be. I concur with tdelaney that it looks like this data is already fine.

Comment: So is there a way to convert \u2764\ufe0f to UTF-8?

Comment: Why do you think you need to? If you think a UTF-8 conversion will help you display this emoji as an emoji, well, it won't.

Comment: It has nothing to do with displaying the emoji. I use a library to extract sentiment from the text and this library is only translating utf-8 encoded emojis. https://github.com/cjhutto/vaderSentiment

Comment: Unicode encoding in JSON is tightly specified, there shouldn't be as much speculation about this as is happening in these comments.

Comment: Have you tried decoding the JSON…‽ I.e. with `json.loads`?

Comment: A quick look at that sentiment analysis thing indicates it doesn't actually need you to UTF-8 encode emojis. The readme is just confusing. The library's emoji lexicon file is UTF-8 encoded, but that gets decoded anyway and doesn't affect how you provide input.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I am afraid it does. I tried the same string with both  \u2764\ufe0f and ❤ and the result for ❤  is correct while for \u2764\ufe0f is not.

Comment: `json.loads` *is* the decoding.

Comment: If you put in `❤` in your source code without an explicit encoding call, then that *wasn't* UTF-8 encoded. Did you put in a plain black ❤ heart, or a red ❤️ heart? `\u2764\ufe0f` is a red ❤️ heart, consisting of a plain ❤ and a variation selector, and [the code's emoji processing](https://github.com/cjhutto/vaderSentiment/blob/master/vaderSentiment/vaderSentiment.py#L242) doesn't handle multi-code-point emojis properly - it loops code point by code point and only checks individual code points against the emoji dict.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I put red heart and it worked then \u2764\ufe0f and it didn't work

Comment: `'\u2764\ufe0f' == '❤️' ` returns `True`.  Both ways generate the same two-codepoint string data.  If you passed the *raw text* `r'\u2764\ufe0f'` or `'\\u2764\\ufe0f'` That is **not the same**.  Those strings are also equivalent but length 12.

Comment: @StamatisTiniakos αν υπήρχε θέμα με το UTF8 δεν θα μπορούσα να γράψω αυτό. If there was any issue with UTF8 I wouldn't be able to write what I just did. We Greeks have been using Unicode exclusively since the late 1990s. Or casually paste all those emojis like ❤ or  ❤️. Post code that actually reproduces your problem and explain *where* that escape sequence appears, *in the question itself*. I'm still not convinced you're not confusing a debugger or console's output for "Unicode encoding".

Comment: @StamatisTiniakos `this library is only translating utf-8 encoded emojis.` there's no such thing as your own question proves. Almost all web pages are UTF8, like this one. Almost all calls to HTTP APIs use UTF8 encoding for their bodies because that's the de-facto default for all libraries. Python 3 strings **are Unicode**, period. When you convert objects to JSON strings, the new strings are still Unicode. *It's only when you make the HTTP call* that *the HTTP library* may have to use a specific **byte encoding** like UTF8 to match the `Content-Type`. Unicode is about bytes, not escapes

Comment: @StamatisTiniakos try capturing the *actual raw HTTP request* and post it in the question, including *your own code*. Perhaps there's no escape sequence to begin with. Perhaps your own code mangles the request body by trying to encode the text when it doesn't have to. Perhaps *the other service has a bug* for the same reason.

Comment: @StamatisTiniakos how do you use that JSON text? How are you using it? *Deserializing it* should handle any escape sequences. Any library that accepts raw JSON text should be able to handle the escape sequences too.

Comment: @StamatisTiniakos Vader Sentiment's examples show it works with plain strings, not JSON. How did you extract and feed the sentences to it? Did you use substring operations or regex instead of deserializing the payload? Deserializing it should have handled any escape sequences. *Post your code*

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I used json.loads(msg.body,strict=False) to decode the json.

Comment: Aaaaaand the result is what?

Comment: @deceze json.loads(msg.body,strict=False) doesn't convert the \u2764\ufe0f to a format that Vader sentiment could recognize.

Comment: What *does* it convert it to? When you `print(repr(msg_body))`, what do you get? Do you get a different result if you take that exact output that's being printed and put it back into Python? There are several levels to this thing, and we're missing most of the information to help you productively. 1. How is the character encoded in JSON? (We see that.) 2. What does it decode to exactly? 3. What are you putting into Vader? 4. What does Vader accept exactly? 5. What result do you expect? 6. What result do you get?

Comment: Then regroup and start from scratch with this problem, JSON-encoding ain't it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s a JSON encoded Unicode character. Decode the JSON, e.g. with `json.loads`, and you’ll get a Python string with a red heart. *If* you need to encode that to UTF-8 encoded `bytes`, use `str.encode` (though likely the library you want to use it with will want normal Python `str`s).

Comment: To be clear, there are 2 Unicode code points in that string.  Together they make the red heart.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224208/discussion-on-answer-by-deceze-convert-u2764-ufe0f-to-utf-8-using-python).